# Spring Data Pageable not supported as RequestParam in Feign Client

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have been trying to expose a Feign Client for my rest api. It takes Pageable as input and has PageDefaults defined.

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping(value = "data", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiOperation(value = "Get Data", nickname = "getData")
public Page<Data> getData(@PageableDefault(size = 10, page = 0) Pageable page,
            @RequestParam(value = "search", required = false) String search) {
    return service.getData(search, page);
}
```

And here is my **feign client:**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "data")
public Page<Data> getData(@RequestParam(name = "pageable", required = false) Pageable page,
            @RequestParam(name = "search", defaultValue = "null", required = false) String search);
```

Now the problem is regardless of whatever page size and page number I send to Feign Client it always applies PageDefaults (0,10).

When I call the rest service directly it works:
http://localhost:8080/data?size=30&page=6

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Greenwich.SR1. Recently a fix was done to support Pageable (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/26#issuecomment-483689346). However I am not sure it the above scenario is not covered or I am missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your code doesn't work because you are using `@RequestParam` annotation for `Pageable` parameter in your Feign method.

My implementation of such a method works as expected.

Client:

```java
@FeignClient(name = "model-service", url = "http://localhost:8080/")
public interface ModelClient {
    @GetMapping("/models")
    Page<Model> getAll(@RequestParam(value = "text", required = false) String text, Pageable page);
}
```

Controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/models")
Page<Model> getAll(@RequestParam(value = "text", required = false, defaultValue = "text") String text, Pageable pageable) {
    return modelRepo.getAllByTextStartingWith(text, pageable);
}
```

---

Note that in my case, without exposing `PageJacksonModule` as a bean, Spring raised the exception:

> InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Page`

So I had to add it to the project:

```java
@Bean
public Module pageJacksonModule() {
    return new PageJacksonModule();
}
```

My working demo: [github.com/Cepr0/sb-feign-client-with-pageable-demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-feign-client-with-pageable-demo)

Comment: Can you please help me with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839485/pagedresourcest-returns-correct-pagemetadata-but-its-content-is-null

Comment: didn't help in my case

Comment: because you forge to also add  SortJacksonModule

Comment: I also needed to add the @Bean with SortJacksonModule, just PageJackson didn't work. But even with the PageJacksonModule and SortJacksonModule  I noticed that response didn't come with all the attributes.

Comment: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page  . any idea on how to fix this