# Spring RestAPI with Feign Client and Pageable

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a working API with all the CRUD methods i need, but i also have a Feign Client, that is throwing me and exception when my pageable GET method is called. I have tried changing it to List<>, but in the end i need it to remain Pageable, i got no clue at this point about what´s going on.

This is the working controller on the original API:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cargos")
public class CargoController {


    @Autowired
    private CargoService cargoService;

    // ACHAR TODOS
    @GetMapping
    public Page<Cargo> consultar(Pageable paginacao) {
        return cargoService.consultar(paginacao);

    }
```

}

This is the Service on the original API:

```
@Service
public class CargoService {
    @Autowired
    private CargoRepositorio repositoryCargos;

    // BUSCA TODOS
    public Page<Cargo> consultar(Pageable paginacao) {
        return repositoryCargos.findAll(paginacao);

    }
}
```

That´s all working, but in the Feign Client, every time the get method is called, it throws and exception:

> catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
>             ReflectionUtils.rethrowRuntimeException(ex.getTargetException());

Here is how my feign client is, i got a service for it:

```
@FeignClient(url="http://localhost:8080/cargos",name="cargo")
public interface CargoFeign {

    //BUSCA TODOS
    @GetMapping
    Page<Cargo> consultar(Pageable paginacao);
```

And the Scheduler:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CargoScheduler {

    @Autowired
    private CargoFeign cargoFeign;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0/1  * * * * *")
    public void executar() {
        log.debug("executando");

// BUSCANDO TODOS OS CARGOS
        Pageable paginacao = PageRequest.of(0, 10, Sort.by( Order.asc("id")));
        Page<Cargo> cargo2 = cargoFeign.consultar(paginacao);
        System.out.println("Listando Cargos");
        System.out.println(cargo2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Resource or Resources provided by spring HATEOAS.
you need to add spring HATEOAS dependency on your client side :

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
```

Enable Spring Boot’s Hypermedia Support in your main class:

```
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
```

and change your feign client:

```
@FeignClient(url="http://localhost:8080/cargos",name="cargo")
public interface CargoFeign {
//BUSCA TODOS
@GetMapping
Resources<Cargo> consultar(Pageable paginacao);
```

Comment: yea, thanks for answearing my dude. I fixed it by passing size and page through the url and creatin a jackson bean on my application.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, this answear helped a little

[Spring Data Pageable not supported as RequestParam in Feign Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021307/spring-data-pageable-not-supported-as-requestparam-in-feign-client)

This is how my feign client looks now

```
//BUSCA TODOS
    @GetMapping("/pagina/{paginaAtual}/tamanho/{tamanho}")
    Page<Cargo> findAll(@PathVariable("paginaAtual") Integer paginaAtual, @PathVariable("tamanho") Integer tamanho);
```